# Python Flask Error ValueError: View function did not return a response

Tags: python, flask

This is my code:

```
@app.route('/registercheck', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def registercheck():
    checkusername = g.db.execute('select uname from users where uname = ?', (request.form['usernameR'], ))
    checkpassword = g.db.execute('select pword from users where uname = ?', (request.form['usernameR'], ))
    arraycheckr = checkpassword.fetchall()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        encryptpword = hashlib.md5()
        encryptpword.update(request.form['passwordR'])
        encryptpword.digest()
        if len(arraycheckr) == 0 and checkpassword == encryptpword:
            if len(request.form['usernameR']) < 6:
                flash('Username must be at least 6 characters')
                return redirect(url_for('register'))
            if len(request.form['passwordR']) < 4:
                flash('Password must be at least 4 characters')
                return redirect(url_for(register))
            if checkusername == request.form['usernameR']:
                flash('Username is already taken')
                return redirect(url_for(register))
            else:
                g.db.execute('insert into users (uname, pword) values (?, ?);', (request.form['usernameR'], encryptpword))
                g.db.commit()
                os.mkdir(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], request.form['usernameR']))
                return redirect(url_for('upload'))
```

I looked at other posts similar to this but I still don't understand why it throws this problem. The redirections look fine (in the html aswell).

Comment: So what does your code return if the method is not POST? Or if it is post and the password is not valid?

Comment: What happens when the request is not a `POST` request etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You accept a GET request witch you never check, at the end you should render a template.

```
@app.route('/registercheck', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def registercheck():
    checkusername = g.db.execute('select uname from users where uname = ?', (request.form['usernameR'], ))
    checkpassword = g.db.execute('select pword from users where uname = ?', (request.form['usernameR'], ))
    arraycheckr = checkpassword.fetchall()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        encryptpword = hashlib.md5()
        encryptpword.update(request.form['passwordR'])
        encryptpword.digest()
        if len(arraycheckr) == 0 and checkpassword == encryptpword:
            if len(request.form['usernameR']) < 6:
                flash('Username must be at least 6 characters')
                return redirect(url_for('register'))
            if len(request.form['passwordR']) < 4:
                flash('Password must be at least 4 characters')
                return redirect(url_for(register))
            if checkusername == request.form['usernameR']:
                flash('Username is already taken')
                return redirect(url_for(register))
            else:
                g.db.execute('insert into users (uname, pword) values (?, ?);', (request.form['usernameR'], encryptpword))
                g.db.commit()
                os.mkdir(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], request.form['usernameR']))
                return redirect(url_for('upload'))
    return render_template('some_file.html')
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, it says:Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Comment: Can you show the updated code?